# Advice on how to delete a software on OSX

Tags: macos

I have a software installed on my OSX computer that affects my daily work so I decide to remove it.
The OSX version is 10.14.3.

I have disabled System Integrity Protection (rootless).

It has a continuous running daemon set up in launchctl.
When I try to run the command "sudo launchctl remove "deamon'name"" to disable the running daemon, I got
sudo: unable to execute /bin/launchctl: Operation not permitted

Of course, remove the files for this software using "sudo rm -rf" failed with "Permission denied"

So how can I remove this software without reinstalling OS?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming and belongs on `Ask Different` site.